# Reorder csv columns/rows from 1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3 to 1, 2, 3,1, 2, 3 , 1,2, 3

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, iterator, series

I need to reorder a csv file which groups the data via an id column ascending from `0` to `184000`.

Unfortunately its `0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3` etc... and I need `1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3` etc.

first instance of `0, 1, 2, 3` etc. making the first series the second instance `0, 1, 2, 3` making the next and so on.

Someone suggested using Python and Pandas but I'm not having any luck figuring it out.

I can read the csv, list the data both columns and rows but cant find a method to sort it based on my requirements.

I've been looking at `pandas.Series` but feel i'm getting my terminology wrong...

So 2 things, what is it called the thing i'm trying to do and does anyone know which sorting method I can use?

Cheers,

Chris

Comment: Can you show how the csv look like and what you expect it to look like?

Comment: Do your columns really have the same names?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add rank to each instance based on the group it belongs to and then sort it by rank and group.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"group": [0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3]})
df['rank'] = df.groupby('group').apply(lambda x: x.rank(method='first'))
df.sort_values(['rank', 'group'])
```

** Update **

Following a comment you can use -

```
df['rank'] = df.groupby('group').rank(method='first')
```

Comment: Cool! Can you explain what rank is doing?

Comment: When. using `method=first` ranks assigned in order they appear in the array.
See documentation here  - https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rank.html

Comment: You can just do `df.groupby(...).rank(method='first')`, [`GroupBy.rank`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.rank.html)

Comment: Do I need to manually insert all occurrence of 0, 1, 2, 3 etc.. in this example?

As mentioned I have 184000 data entries relating to 1152 particles...


EDIT: maybe I'm using the word "Group" incorrect here in terms of programming?

in my csv the numbers have been inserted together, 0's with 0's, 1's with 1's etc..

the numbers in question are the particle id's.

Comment: I assume it appears in the data somewhere or can be computed

Comment: I'm getting errors using: df['rank'] = df.groupby('group').rank(method='first')

I'm trying to mitigate the manual input by passing: df['rank'] = df.groupby('id').rank(method='first')

id = the column name of the id data

error: KeyError: 'rank' / ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 9, placement implies 1